# Appcelerator Titanium: createHTTPClient fails with same data that works in GUI REST client

Tags: rest, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

REST Client returns "200 OK" - Thats good!

[image]

createHTTPClient returns "HTTP error" with the exact same data. When I remove the payoad I get a response, when I add the payload in client.send(payload) I get the error. I do need to pass the payload for future requests.

```
var payload = { 
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
    };

 var url = "https://MYWEBSITE.com/rest_login/user/token.json";

 var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
         alert('success');
     },
     // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.error(e.error);
         alert('error');
     },
     timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
 });
 // Prepare the connection.
 client.open("POST", url);
 client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 // Send the request.
 client.send(payload);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change last line to this:

```
client.send( JSON.stringify(payload) );
```

The reason is that since you are setting content-type to application json, so you need to stringify your input data of dictionary object so that server can parse it as per header set.

Comment: That worked! I was thrown off by "If you pass a serializable JavaScript object, it is automatically turned into form-encoded POST data. You can also send an arbitrary string or binary data (in the form of a Titanium.Blob)." from the documenttion for the send() method in createHTTPClient.

Comment: LiveView ON state doesn't affect web-services calls. It mostly affects callbacks of e.g. Push Notification.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what kind of error you get, but I guess the problem is that you try to send an object while payload is expected to be text (you have `client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` in you code) . Try this:

```
// Send the request.
 client.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
```

Comment: That worked! I was thrown off by "If you pass a serializable JavaScript object, it is automatically turned into form-encoded POST data. You can also send an arbitrary string or binary data (in the form of a Titanium.Blob)." from the documenttion for the send() method in createHTTPClient.

Comment: @AdamG nice to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.onload = function(e) {

        var myObjectString = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        alert(myObjectString.token);
        Ti.API.info("Received text: " + myObjectString.token);
    };

    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.error(e.error);
        alert('error');
    };

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://my.cgps.org/rest_login/user/token.json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xhr.send();
```

Hope this helps. I think you did not handle send parameter properly in your API call.

Comment: I need to send post variables for username and password along as well. How do I include those?